# Why is my fetch request causing an exception when using an NSExpression max: on it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am performing a *fetch request*, using an **NSPredicate** to eliminate some objects from the initial selection, and using an **NSExpression** to then retrieve only the maximum value of a date attribute of the *managed objects*. I am using exactly the same code as Apple gives in its example ([Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6)), however, it seems that this expression is somehow considering the attribute for which I want the maximum as an *array*, so every time I perform the *fetch*, the app crashes with an '*unrecognised selector*' exception (trying to send the *count* message to an **__NSDate** instance). If I change the attribute name to a *string* attribute, then I get the same exception for an **__NSCFString** instance or equivalent), which implies to me that it is finding objects and using the right attribute, but somehow the expression is not being applied correctly.

My code is:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BridgeOpening" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastUpdated != nil && bridge.location == %@", location];

// Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

// Create an expression for the key path.
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"lastUpdated"];

// Create an expression to represent the maximum value at the key path 'creationDate'
NSExpression *maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

// Create an expression description using the maxExpression and returning a date.
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

// The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value.
[expressionDescription setName:@"maxDate"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:maxExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

// Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error = nil;
NSLog(@"executing fetch");
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"fetch finished");
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
else {
    if ([objects count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Minimum date: %@", [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxDate"]);
        lastUpdate = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxDate"];
    }
}
```

The 'fetch finished' log is never reached, so the exception is definitely cause by executing the *fetch request*.

Does anyone have any idea as to why whatever the expression is doing seems to expect an **NSArray**, or know what I am doing wrong?
I should add that if I do the *fetch request* without the *expression* (and **NSManagedObjectResultType**) there is no problem, and if my *predicate* is such that there are no results before the *expression* is applied then there are no problems.

I think this is probably the same problem as encountered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927981/calculating-the-max-value-for-a-core-data-attribute-nscfnumber-error), but there is no accepted solution and the answer the original poster gave is not acceptable (using **NSManagedObjectResultType** instead of **NSDictionaryResultType**, which I think just bypasses the *expression* altogether, and almost certainly negates the memory advantage of using an *expression*.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to state this originally, but I have the same problem whether or not I use a *predicate* with the *fetch request*.

Comment: Apple's sample code from your link doesn't use a predicate for the fetch request, so what happens if you don't set `request.predicate` ?

Comment: Exactly the same thing happens if I don't use a predicate - but thanks - I should have included that originally.